# Trigger update multiple field in MySql/MariaDB

Tags: mysql, triggers, mariadb

I need to create a single trigger that runs after inserting a row in the table Documenti and makes the 2 updates shown in the following query

```sql
UPDATE AllegatoZip AS a
    LEFT JOIN Documenti AS d on d.allegato = a.idAllegato
        SET a.data_invio_operatore = d.data_invio_doc
WHERE NEW.allegato = a.idAllegato AND NEW.data_invio_doc > a.data_invio_operatore;


UPDATE AllegatoZip AS a SET a.dataInserimento = now()
    WHERE NEW.allegato = a.idAllegato;
```

The trigger I created with just one update works

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER AggiornaDataDocumenti AFTER INSERT ON Documenti
    FOR EACH ROW UPDATE AllegatoZip a
        LEFT JOIN Documenti d on a.idAllegato = d.allegato
            SET a.data_invio_operatore = d.data_invio_doc
        WHERE NEW.allegato = a.idAllegato AND NEW.data_invio_doc > a.data_invio_operatore
```

SQL Database model: https://ibb.co/msnvNe

PS. sorry for my English

**UPDATE: I SOLVED**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `AggiornaDataDocumenti` AFTER INSERT ON `Documenti` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE docID INT;
SET docID = NEW.allegato;

UPDATE AllegatoZip a
LEFT JOIN Documenti d on a.idAllegato = d.allegato
SET a.data_invio_operatore = d.data_invio_doc
WHERE  
docID = a.idAllegato AND d.data_invio_doc > a.data_invio_operatore;

UPDATE AllegatoZip a SET a.dataInserimento = now()
WHERE 
docID = a.idAllegato;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Put a comma after the first set col = col and the put your second expression. example: ```SET a.col1 = b.col1, a.col2 = b.col2```

Comment: The first expression  SET a.data_invio_operatore = d.data_invio_doc  must satisfy NEW.allegato = a.idAllegato AND NEW.data_invio_doc > a.data_invio_operatore 
while the second only NEW.allegato = a.idAllegato;